# Is it possible to automate the combination of excel cells

Tags: python, excel, vba, lookup

I have data in an excel file organized like this:

```
Hitter         Pitcher            xBA
Mike Trout     Clayton Kershaw
Bryce Harper   Jacob deGrom
```

In another Sheet of the file I have data set up like this

```
      A               B                C   
1 Player Name    Clayton Kershaw  Jacob deGrom 
2 Bryce Harper      .360               .345
3 Mike Trout        .456               .298
```

I want to know if there is a way to get the number data from a matchup based on the way the data is organized in the first sheet.

Basically, if Bryce Harper is in hitter column and Jacob deGrom is in pitcher column, then get the data from cell C2 from the second sheet and put in the corresponding cell in the xBA column in the same row as Bryce Harper and Jacob deGrom.

So it ends up looking like this

```
Hitter         Pitcher            xBA
Mike Trout     Clayton Kershaw
Bryce Harper   Jacob deGrom      .345
```

I have about 200 combinations to run through and manually looking it up and then copy and pasting is very tedious and time consuming.

I'm open to having to run this through python or R if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a "2D" or "two-way" lookup  - see for example  http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/two-way-lookup.html

Comment: I assume that's a typo in the question?  OP references C2 but that's the C3 value.

Comment: Yeah horrible question name...I focused so much on explaining it that i forgot about that...but yes it is a typo it is supposed to be C2 though. I'll look into the two-way lookup and come back. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score -1):

@Jake, this Vlookup with If will solve the problem.

=IF(AND(A2 ="Bryce", B2="Jacob"), Vlookup (C2, A2:D20, 3,0))

NB:  Adjust the Data Range.